# force layout set fixed distance each nodes even after dragging

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have searched but did not achieve this, is it possible that when every nodes are created there should be fixed distance of each node even after dragging.

please check this code

```
var width = 1280,
    height = 800

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(1)
    .linkDistance (800)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);




var datajson = {
  "nodes" : [ {"name" : "a", "group" : 2,'x' : 200,'y' : 300} , {"name" : "b", "group" : 1,'x' : 200,'y' : 300}, { "name" : "c", "group" : 1 ,'x' : 200,'y' : 300}, {"name" : "d", "group" : 2,'x' : 200,'y' : 300} ],
  "links" : [{"source": 0 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 1},{"source": 0 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 2},{"source": 2 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 3},
  {"source": 1 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 4},{"source": 2 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 5,"distance":3},{"source": 0 ,"target" : 2 , "value" : 5,"distance":30},{"source": 1 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 5, 'class': 'red',"distance":30}
  ]
}


  force
      .nodes(datajson.nodes)
      .links(datajson.links)
      .start();




  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(datajson.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(datajson.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 45)
      .attr("height", 45)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
    var imagePath =
           "http://www.bigbiz.com/bigbiz/icons/ultimate/Comic/Comic"
           + rnd.toString() + ".gif";

    return imagePath;
});

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
  });
```

Comment: What I manage to set Initial position when document initialized  by this <code>var datajson = {
  "nodes" : [ {"name" : "a", "group" : 2, "x":65, "y":43, "fixed":"TRUE"} , {"name" : "b", "group" : 1,"x":465, "y":43, "fixed":"TRUE"}, { "name" : "c", "group" : 1, "x":465, "y":343, "fixed":"TRUE" }, {"name" : "d", "group" : 2,"x":65, "y":343, "fixed":"TRUE"} ]
}
</code>
But when draging it is acting its default behavior , I want set each node position to initial position (x,y) after draging to anywhere. 
Any advice will be helpful . Thanks

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. If you drag a node you will drag it away from the other nodes, i.e drag a single node. If you want to keep the distance the same, you will, in effect, be dragging all nodes at once ? Could you explain what it is you want in a bit more detail

Comment: yes, I managed to get each node to its initial x,y position. Now I need the bouncing effect before each node gets fixed to its initial position.

Comment: Hi , @thatOneGuy Please see my answer , I have done this. But bouncing effect is missing . What I am looking for now .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to fixed to each node to its initial position. Here is working example but here missing the bouncing effect that is not achieved yet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  stroke: #dfdfdf;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.link.red {
    stroke: blue;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1280,
    height = 800

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.15)
    .linkDistance (400)
    .charge(-100)
    .size([width, height]);




var node_psoition = [{"x":65, "y":43},{"x":665, "y":43},{"x":465, "y":343},{"x":65, "y":343}]
var datajson = {
  "nodes" : [ {"id":1,"name" : "a", "group" : 2, "x":65, "y":43 , "fixed":"TRUE"} , {"id":2,"name" : "b", "group" : 1,"x":665, "y":43, "fixed":"TRUE"}, { "id":3,"name" : "c", "group" : 1, "x":465, "y":343, "fixed":"TRUE" }, {"id":4,"name" : "d", "group" : 2,"x":65, "y":343, "fixed":"TRUE"} ],
  "links" : [{"source": 0 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 1},{"source": 0 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 1},{"source": 2 ,"target" : 3 , "value" : 1},
  {"source": 2 ,"target" : 1 , "value" : 1}
  ]
}



  force
      .nodes(datajson.nodes)
      .links(datajson.links)
      .start();


var drag = force.drag()
    .on("dragend", dragend);


  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(datajson.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(datajson.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("image")
      .attr("x", -8)
      .attr("y", -8)
      .attr("width", 45)
      .attr("height", 45)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 64 + 1);
    var imagePath =
           "http://www.bigbiz.com/bigbiz/icons/ultimate/Comic/Comic"
           + rnd.toString() + ".gif";

    return imagePath;
});

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 12)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

   });

  function dragend(d) {

 
        force.stop();
        position = (d.id - 1);
        temp_x = node_psoition[position].x;
        temp_y = node_psoition[position].y;

        d.x = d.px = temp_x;
        d.y = d.py = temp_y;
        d.fixed = true;
        force.start();

 


  }



</script>
```

Comment: is there any way to give a bouncing effect to above nodes ?